According to theistic evolutionist Christians, did the dinosaurs transgress so that God allowed their destruction?
According to theistic evolutionist Christians, did God allow their destruction because these creatures had done something to warrant it?
This is because God is all knowing and knew from the moment that comet began moving that it was headed for earth and could have done something to stop it from causing this destruction but let it happen, and the most plausible reason for God allowing this is if those creatures had sinned and hence guilty.
The hermeneutic reference that shows God had foreknowledge about that comet is this verse.
1 John 3:20

For if our heart condemns us, God is greater than our heart, and knows all things.


Why not ask a more recent question about the extinction of saber tooth tigers? Or better yet, dodos (1681) or passenger pigeons (1914)? I'm pretty sure there is no evidence that dodos were significantly more sinful than any other animal.¶  "did the dinosaurs transgress" unjustifiably assumes something as true. Before asking this question one should first get an answer to "Which denominations believe that animals are capable of sin?", otherwise this is a loaded question.

Animals do not have consciousness therefore cannot sin because sin comes by knowledge of the law--knowledge which is unattainable to an animal.

Romans 7:7 What shall we say then? Is the law sin? Certainly not! On the contrary, I would not have known sin except through the law. For I would not have known covetousness unless the law had said, “You shall not covet.”


John 9:41 Jesus said to them, “If you were blind, you would have no sin; but now you say, ‘We see.’ Therefore your sin remains.

Regarding the destruction of the dinosaurs: if you study the human brain, you'll find that the core (basal ganglia) is reptilian, limbic system is paleomammalian and the neocortex is neomammalian. This is called the triune brain.
In some denominations which accept theistic evolution, the theory is that one of God's purposes for the dinosaur was the evolution of the reptilian brain, which would be the core function of the human brain. Meaning the purpose of dinosaurs was pointing toward the creation of mankind. The reptilian brain, once satisfactorily perfected, would be used in man.
When Project Dinosaur was complete then Project Mammal was initiated as the next step towards the development of the human brain.
Even if the aforementioned theory is debated among denominations or individuals, God's work has always been for the creation of mankind. God is sovereign and has the divine right to choose what animals survive or die. Dinosaurs were likely part of God's overall evolutionary plan and when their usefulness had run out, they were destroyed. Earth was given a clean slate to proceed to the next project.
Thy will be done on earth as it is in heaven.
Whatever God wills, whether to create dinosaurs or to destroy dinosaurs, He makes all the final decision according to His grand purpose.

But you do believe that God is rational and does everything based on a reason, and if he willed for those dinosaurs to die then there must be a reason behind it.

But that would be calling for speculation and not really an answer.

I gave a speculative answer: they were part of an evolutionary plan and when their usefulness ran out, they were removed, but this is speculation as any theory would be. It's not for man to know everything God has planned. I'm not sure what the motive of your question regarding dinosaurs is or why this is particularly important to you.
